# App vs Mobile Website for NFC Tags Pros/Cons

Tags: android, ios, blackberry, mobile, nfc

I'm presently looking into building a mobile solution that works with Near Field Communication (NFC) tags.

This would be used mainly in large urban cities to allow users to quickly receive a url which leads to a mobile website.

This first stage would have to be mobile web, because NFC tags can't launch an app, but for the second set of interactions and ongoing retention what would the main pro/cons be of using a mobile website over a native app?

Comment: You do know that iOS has no NFC chip, right?

Comment: @JustSid yeah, I've identified 8 reasonably popular handsets (Tocco, Galaxy S2, Galaxy S3, BB 9900, BB 9360, BB 9790, and BB 9380) that have NFC implemented. Since the Galaxy S3 has one it's a reasonable bet that the iPhone 5 will.

Comment: NFC tags can actually launch apps on Android. See e.g. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/nfc/nfc.html#aar

Comment: @NFCguy very useful information, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For any mass-deployment solution the tag with the URL NDEF record would be the only option, since you cannot make any assumption about the fact if the application is or is not installed. Also the tag can be read by NFC phones with different operating systems, do it would be better to have the mobile optimized web site.

As for Android I believe that at the end of 2012 almost every phone will come with NFC - there is now ~20 models available and new are coming, the NFC is on many RIM and Symbian (well and N9 MeeGo) devices and Nokia is starting with NFC in WP7 (see Lumia 610). As for iPhone, there is the iCarte accessory but it is not deployed on large scale, but the rumors says the iPhone5 comes with NFC...

Of course you can offer the application download on the mobile web site via link to the proper application store.

BR
STeN